# select string type 8 digit + one letter

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
$dnisList = @"
    jimenex joe, maria . 73337789N
    jerse joan juana usuaria 73637089N.
"@
    
$dnisList.Trim().Split("`n") | where-object {
    $a = $_ | select-string -pattern '^(\d{8})([A-Z])$'
    write-host $a
}
```

output:

```
juan mar yoy . 73337789N
juena juose jua, usuaria 73637089N.
```

How do I clean the document to keep only the digits?

output expected:

```
73337789N
73637089N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
$dnisList = @"
    juan mar yoy . 73337789N
    juena juose jua, usuaria 73637089N.
"@
$pattern = "(\d{8})([A-Z])"
$results = $dnisList | Select-String $pattern -AllMatches | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Value}
$results
```

---

And you will get as output like this :

```
73337789N
73637089N
```

Comment: how would it be to just extract `jerse joan` `jimenez joe` ?